# Execute mvn archetype:generate with User Input from Java Code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I am creating a project from a custom archetype in Spring Boot
Here are the steps

1. Created a Template Project
2. Executed `mvn archetype:create-from-project -Darchetype.properties=../myCustom.properties` command from Java Code and created a custom archetype from template
3. Installed custom archetype into Local maven Repo.
   `cd target\generated-sources\archetype`
   `mvn clean install`
4. Create project from Custom Archetype  (This is the problem area)
   `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.mycompany -DarchetypeArtifactId=myApp-template-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Ddomain="archetypeDomain"`

So till point 3, I am able to execute commands from Java Project.

The maven command in #4., Java Code remains stuck and does not prompt user input. However, we execute the same command (`mvn archetype:generate` ) from Command Prompt, it asks user input (which is expected and desired).

Now, I am not getting any idea on why the Java application does not prompt for user input but in command prompt it does.

Thanks in Advance.. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to execute the command using following parameters

`mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.mycompany -DarchetypeArtifactId=myApp-template-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -Ddomain="archetypeDomain" -DinteractiveMode=false`

By running the above command, I managed to took get it worked.